# Capturing Email click activity in a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I am looking for a method of capturing a subscriber's click activity in a data extension. Ideally utilising the link Alias combined with the subscriberID.

Simple Use case sample:

Subscriber receives [Email 1] and clicks on "Destination - Spain" and "Destination - Portugal" which link through to our transactional website. On click the subscriberID and link Alias are captured into a Data Extension.

Subscriber receivers [Email 2] which contains an ordered list of destinations and based upon a lookup into the above DE features "Spain" and "Portugal" in the subject line and highlights these two destinations as "FEATURED".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You'll need SFMC Support to enable the [System Data Views](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/).   The [_Click](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_click/) System Data View is a record of all clicks by Subscriber.  You could write a [Query Activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) to add rows to a [Data Extension](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/).

Comment: The theory here is to query all clicks and add rows to a Data Extension, doing so a scheduled or automated process?

Comment: You could definitely automate it in [Automation Studio](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/automation_studio/).

Comment: Simple as that - delayed reaction but this is incredibly powerful.